# SortedSet.Remove() doesn't remove element returned by SortedSet.Min

Tags: c#, sortedset

I'm trying to implement a custom sorted Queue where items are sorted in this way:

- If both items have the same parent path, sort them in FIFO manner
- If items have different parent path, the item with bigger index should be dequeued first.

I've implemented it using the `SortedSet`. The problem is that while it generally works, in some cases, e.g. lots of adding and removing items at random, `_mSortedSet.Remove(entry)` returns false.

I've implemented it as such:

```
public class CustomSortingQueue<T> : IComparer<(T work, string fullPath, ulong index)>
    {
        private readonly SortedSet<(T work, string fullPath, ulong index)> _mSortedSet;
        private readonly Comparer<ulong> _mIndexComparer = Comparer<ulong>.Default;

        private ulong _mNextIndex = 0;

        public CustomSortingQueue() {
            _mSortedSet = new SortedSet<(T work, string fullPath, ulong index)>(this);
        }

        public int Compare((T work, string fullPath, ulong index) x, (T work, string fullPath, ulong index) y)
        {
            if (x.fullPath == y.fullPath)
            {
                // For same paths we want to do normal counting - e.g. bigger index means should be done later
                return _mIndexComparer.Compare(x.index, y.index);
            }

            // For different paths, we want the new one to be done as fast as possible -> bigger index should be done faster
            return _mIndexComparer.Compare(y.index, x.index);
        }

        public void Enqueue(T work, string fullPath)
        {
            _mSortedSet.Add((work, fullPath, _mNextIndex++));
        }

        public (T work, string fullPath) Dequeue()
        {
            var entry = _mSortedSet.Min;
            _mSortedSet.Remove(entry);
            return (entry.work, entry.fullPath);
        }
    }
```

In the cases it fails I found that `Remove` returns false from `sortedset.cs` by failing `if (Is2Node(current))`.

Looking in the debugger at my `_mSortedSet` I can see that it has items like this (I'll be skipping the exact values of the T parameter for brevity, as it's unused in comparison):

```
(T, "Y:\\", 538),
(T, "Y:\\", 566),
(T, "Y:\\", 570),
...
(T, "X:\\", 537),
(T, "X:\\", 546),
(T, "X:\\", 595),
...
(T, null, 531),
(T, null, 532),
...
(T, null, 740),
(T, "Y:\\", 530),
(T, "Z:\\", 529)
```

The `_mSortedSet.Min` is `(T, "Y:\\", 538)`. I see that the most probable culprit is the second to last item, which has a curious place in the output. My best guess is that something inside the sorted set breaks when recomputing the weighted tree.

I suspect this might be a problem in my `Compare` function (as is the case with most Remove problems) but I cannot pinpoint exactly why. Any help with understanding why the `Remove` fails even though `Min` is found would be greatly appreciated. Am I using the SortedSet for a wrong use-case?

Comment: I believe your comparison basically breaks the required contract of `IComparer`. Ignoring the first parameter, `(x, 1) < (x, 3)`, `(y, 2) < (x, 1)`, `(x, 3) < (y, 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your comparer is not transitive, and comparers *need* to be transitive when sorting items.

The sorted collections all rely on there being a *single* valid ordering of items, and do not support collections with numerous valid orderings, which is the case given your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed the fact the transitive property is a requirement, doh. So that means that I have to roll my own, probably O(n) at best, sorting collection, right? Or do you have any recommendations for something that might sort the items in this way without needing the transitive property?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help with the *transitive* property! For posterity - I've found that using the `SortedSet` wasn't giving much performance improvements in my use-case so I just went with a normal
`List<(string, Queue<T>)> _mBuckets` instead.

where

```
private List<(string, Queue<T>)> _mBuckets = new List<string, Queue<T>)>();
public void Enqueue(T work, string fullPath)
{
    var foundItem = _mBuckets.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Item1 == fullPath);
    if (foundItem.Equals(default))
    {
      // New paths are always pushed first
      _mBuckets.Insert(0, (fullPath, new Queue<T>(new T[] { work })));
    }
    else
    {
       foundItem.Item2.Enqueue(work);
    }
}
```